# DateTime validates date only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have added date-time validation for two fields(starts at, ends at) My params are as follows

```
"user"=>{

"starts_at(1i)"=>"2013", 

"starts_at(2i)"=>"12", 

"starts_at(3i)"=>"3", 

"starts_at(4i)"=>"09", 

"starts_at(5i)"=>"47", 

"ends_at(1i)"=>"2013", 

"ends_at(2i)"=>"12", 

"ends_at(3i)"=>"10", 

"ends_at(4i)"=>"01",

"ends_at(5i)"=>"47"}
```

**controller.rb**

```
def create
  ann = params[:user]
  start_date = DateTime.civil ann["starts_at(1i)"].to_i, ann["starts_at(2i)"].to_i, ann["starts_at(3i)"].to_i, ann["starts_at(4i)"].to_i, ann["starts_at(5i)"].to_i
  end_date = DateTime.civil ann["ends_at(1i)"].to_i, ann["ends_at(2i)"].to_i, ann["ends_at(3i)"].to_i, ann["ends_at(4i)"].to_i, ann["ends_at(5i)"].to_i
  if start_date <= end_date
    //codes to create user page
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Ends at should be greater than starts at'
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

The above validates only date field. It does not show up validation for time field. If I inspect `starts_at` and `ends_at` my log gives

```
Tue, 03 Dec 2013 09:47:00 +0000

Tue, 10 Dec 2013 01:47:00 +0000
```

How can I change my code to validate time also??

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare after converting your DateTime to Timestamp. Since, timestamp is an integer value, calculations will be more accurate.